# Storing all items from Graph API at once

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have my `reportSchema.js` which is where my schema is defined. I am storing the JSON I get back from the `Microsoft Graph API` into a variable called `result`. I want to store each value in the `result` array into `mongodb`. I am able to access individual items from the array like this

```
receivedDateTime: result.value[0].receivedDateTime,

sentDateTime: result.value[1].sentDateTime
```

But I want to be able to store everything at once. How can I go about doing this? I will post the code down below.

`reportSchema`

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var sera = mongoose.Schema({
    isRead: Boolean,
    subject: String,
    from: String,
    receivedDateTime: Date,
    sentDateTime: Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("SERA", sera)
```

`sample of result array`

```
value: [{
            '@odata.etag': 'W/"CQAAAA=="',
            id: 'AAMkADg4MTBkNmRiLTAwNzQtNDE1Ny1hNjlkLWVjNzE5N2M1MGEwMgBGAAAAAAA9yT6uaq2hTrV0L6GqHQ_CBwALVVFnK27cQ4tC6FzqOc3cAAAAAAEMAAALVVFnK27cQ4tC6FzqOc3cAANuNGz-AAA=',
            receivedDateTime: '2019-03-09T03:45:45Z',
            sentDateTime: '2019-03-09T03:45:44Z',
            subject: 'Re: hw3',
            isRead: true,
            from: {
                emailAddress: {
                    name: 'Example',
                    address: 'example.yahoo.com'
                }
            }
        }]
```

`how I am saving the report`

```
   SERA.insertMany(result.value, function (error, success) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("There has been an error inserting")
                } else {
                    console.log("The API data has been stored")
                }
            })
            // save stores into database
            SERA.save().then(result => {
                console.log(result)
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("The error is " + error)
            });
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Handling post request to /api/report",
                createdReport: report
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use insertMany() it accepts array of values you want to save.

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose')

 var sera = mongoose.Schema({
    isRead: Boolean,
    subject: String,
    from: {
      emailAddress: {
         name: String,
         address: String
      }
    },
    receivedDateTime: Date,
    sentDateTime: Date
 });

 const Sera = mongoose.model("SERA", sera)

 const values = [{
        id: 'AAMkADg4MTBkNmRiLTAwNzQtNDE1Ny1hNjlkLWVjNzE5N2M1MGEwMgBGAAAAAAA9yT6uaq2hTrV0L6GqHQ_CBwALVVFnK27cQ4tC6FzqOc3cAAAAAAEMAAALVVFnK27cQ4tC6FzqOc3cAANuNGz-AAA=',
        receivedDateTime: '2019-03-09T03:45:45Z',
        sentDateTime: '2019-03-09T03:45:44Z',
        subject: 'Re: hw3',
        isRead: true,
        from: {
            emailAddress: {
                name: 'Example',
                address: 'example.yahoo.com'
            }
        }
    }]

  Sera.insertMany(values, (error, docs) => {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(docs);
    }
  });

  // alternative
  // Sera.insertMany(values).then(docs => {
  //    console.log(docs)
  // })
  // .catch(error => {
  //   console.log(error)
  // })
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany

Comment: hmm okay. Based on how I am saving above what would I need to change? I updated the post.

Comment: you can directly access insertMany() without creating instance of your model. Just do Sera.insertMany(result.value)

Comment: I did `SERA.insertMany(result.value)` but it did not execute? Should I create an instance beforehand?

Comment: did you try to then() it after insertMany()?

Comment: the data is saved once you successfully called insertMany(). you do not need to call save() after insertMany(). You can access the result from the callback, in your case you named it "success". try to console log your "success" variable in your callback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190272/discussion-between-gerald-and-moegizzle).